# how can i pass my context variables to javascript in Django?

Tags: django

views.py

```
context = {'select_company': select_company,}
return render(request, 'invest/chart.html', context)
```

html

```
<option value="{{o}}">{{select_company}}</option>----------{{select_company}} can show its value
```

```
<script>
company = {{select_company|safe}}; ---------------js tell me undefined
</script>
```

django 2.2 python 3.7
how to solve the weird problem

Comment: Is your script embedded in your django template or in a separate file? If in your template, look at the source in your browser. You might need to quote the string, if it's supposed to be string: `var company = "{{ select_company|safe }}"`

Comment: var company = "{{ select_company|safe }}" is what i want and solved the problem, the answer about data attributes is another solution.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe data attributes:

your_template.html

```
<div id="some-element" data-company="{{ selected_company }}"></div>
```

your_javascript.js

```
const element = document.querySelector('#some-element');

console.log(element.dataset.company);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to assign a template variable to a **string** in javascript, you need to add the quotes. `{{ select_company|safe }}` will just expand the string in your template so you end up with:

```
var company = some string;
```

Since `some` isn't defined as variable, you get an "undefined" error.

Always do this:

```
var company = "{{ select_company|safe }}";
```

which will render as

```
var company = "some company";
```

*Tip*: Always take a look at the rendered source code in your browser developer tools when you get errors in your HTML pages, you will spot these kind of mistakes much easier.